# Trying to get the correct output from JQ

Tags: jq

I'm trying to get this output the device name "test"

My filter is `.[] | [.deviceName]` and it's returning error: (at :7): `Cannot index array with string "deviceName"`

```
{
    "test": [
        {
            "deviceName": "test",
            "monitoringServer": "server1"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you meant:

```
jq '.test[] | [.deviceName]'
```

or perhaps:

```
jq '.[][] | [.deviceName]'
```

but without knowing your requirements, it's hard to say.  That's one of the reasons why the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines were formulated.